# Background image in HTML using CSS, no errors but image not appearing

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for a school project and I want to add a background image. the image is not appearing and I have checked with my teacher but she doesn't know what is wrong.

css:

```
.body {
    background-image: url('img\smile.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 3):

You might need to remove the dot before body and also add the closing bracket.

Answer (score 3):

1. In CSS, we use dot only for referring to classes. **body is a tag.** Hence
   remove the dot before the body tag and make sure to close the body with curly
   braces.
2. And also you can use **shorthand property** to make the css more simple.
   For example,

   ```
   body {
   background-image: url('img\smile.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   }
   ```

instead of this you can just make it as,

```
    body {
    background: url('img\smile.png') no-repeat fixed cover;
    }
```

Reference Link -> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_shorthand.asp